# Overload C++ method with template arguments : how to make this work for subclass of template?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I want to write two overloads of a method, one with arguments that are instances of a specific template, and one for "everything else". This works when the arguments are instances of the template specialization, but doesn't work for subclasses of the template specialization.  For example:

```
template <class T> class Ptr { public: T* ptr; };
class C {};
typedef Ptr<C> CPtr;
class CPtrSub : public CPtr {};
template <class T> void foo(const T& a, const T& b) {
    std::cout << "plain\n";
}
template <class T> void foo(const Ptr<T>& a, const Ptr<T>& b) {
    std::cout << "ptr\n";
}
int main() {
    CPtr p1, p2;
    CPtrSub p3, p4;
    foo(p1, p2);
    foo(p3, p4);
}
```

When I run this, the output is:

```
ptr
plain
```

Is it possible to build an overload that is selected for subclasses of the template in addition to the template itself?

UPDATE: Peter's answer is so close!  But "convertible to Ptr<T> isn't the right question.  Because T is never convertible to Ptr<T>.  I need it to be conditioned on "convertible to Ptr<V> for *some* V".

So this works to avoid the specific specialization CPtr:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<T, CPtr>::value >::type >
void foo(const T& a, const T& b) {
    std::cout << "plain\n";
}
```

But attempts to go down the path of "convertible to Ptr<V> for some V" produce compile error (cannot deduce V):

```
template <typename T, typename V, typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible_v<T, Ptr<V> > >::value >
void foo(const T& a, const T& b) {
    std::cout << "plain\n";
}
```

I did, however, find a solution that works in my case but perhaps is not fully general.  If I make my Ptr template inherit from some other class I can test on that class instead.  This code:

```
class PtrBase {};
template <class T> class Ptr : public PtrBase { public: T * ptr; };
class C {};
typedef Ptr<C> CPtr;
class CPtrSub : public CPtr {};
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if<!std::is_convertible<T, PtrBase>::value >::type >
void foo(const T& a, const T& b) {
    std::cout << "plain\n";
}
template <class T> void foo(const Ptr<T>& a, const Ptr<T>& b) {
    std::cout << "ptr\n";
}
int main() {
    C c1, c2;
    CPtr p1, p2;
    CPtrSub p3, p4;
    foo(c1, c2);
    foo(p1, p2);
    foo(p3, p4);
}
```

Produces the output

```
plain
ptr
ptr
```

So Peter's answer did lead to the right place.  It would still be nice to know if there is a general answer that doesn't rely on the template base class.

FINAL NOTE: Some of these meta-programming features are available in C++ 11, C++ 17, and C++ 20.  I downgraded the usage to things available C++ 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to dip into some template metaprogramming here.  The problem is that your first overload is a "better" match for `Ptr<T>` subclasses because it doesn't require any sort of conversion.  You can fix this by removing it from the overload set.  Something like:

```
template <class T> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<T, Ptr<T>>
foo (const T& a, const T& b)
{
    /* details */
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, this got me to the right answer.  But see my updates for the gory details. -- john